# Como verificar si un email existe en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo el siguiente código de PHP para insertar datos en la tabla de passwords, pero también tengo una tabla de usuarios donde almaceno todos los registros de usuarios (email, nickname, etc.). Quisiera que de alguna forma este mismo código comprobara que el email existe realmente en la tabla usuarios antes de insertarlo en la tabla passwords. Ya lo intente de varias maneras pero sigue sin funcionar.

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
$email = "";
$email_alert = "";
$bytes = random_bytes(5);
$token =bin2hex($bytes);


$query = $link->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE email= ?");
$stmt->execute(array($email));

$emailExiste = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if ($emailExiste > 0) {
  include "mail_reset.php";
    if($enviado){
      $link->query(" insert into passwords(email, token, codigo)
      values('$email','$token','$codigo') ") or die($link->error);
      $email_alert = "Se ha enviado tu código para restablecer la contraseña";

} else {
      $email_alert = "No existe ninguna cuenta asociada al correo";
}
}

?>
```

Mi formulario esta de la siguiente manera:

```
<form id="form-recu" action="/php/restablecer.php" method="POST" target="envio">

        <div class="user-details">

<h3 style="text-align: center;">Ingresa tu correo electrónico para recibir un código para restablecer tu contraseña.</h3><br><br>

          <div class="input-box">
              <div class="input-field">
            <span class="details">Correo Electrónico</span>
            <input id="correo" type="email" href="#" maxlength="60" name="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu correo" required>
            <i class="uil uil-envelope email-icon"></i></div>
          </div>

<!--Utilizo ajax para realizar el envio sin recargar-->
<iframe name="envio" style="position:absolute; top:-1500px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Cómo estás poblando la variable email para comparar? En tu código es siempre vacío. Y lo otro, en lo que probaste, has revisado qué recibes en el contenido de $emailExiste?

Comment: Hola gracias por responder. Ya intenté dándole a la variable $email el valor de POST pero tampoco de esta manera logré nada.

Comment: Puedes agregar el formulario donde ingresan los datos, y así comprender mejor tu problema.

Comment: Habría que ver cómo lo haces y desde qué formulario envías la info. Edita la pregunta y añade eso

Comment: Listo he agregado mi formulario.

Comment: El posible problema que veo es que nunca capturas el email, de hecho en el primer bloque de código en la 3ra línea tienes `$email = "";` debería ser `$email = $_POST['email'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de varias horas pude dar con la solución al problema. Anexo la manera en la que pude conseguirlo.

```
    <?php
        require_once "conexion.php";
        
    // Definir variables e inicializar con valores vacios
        $email = "";
        $email_err = "";
    
    
     // VALIDANDO INPUT DE EMAIL
            if(empty(trim($_POST["email"]))){
                 echo "El email existe";
            }else{
                //prepara una declaracion de seleccion
                $sql = "SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE email = ?";
                
                if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_email);
                    
                    $param_email = trim($_POST["email"]);
                    
                    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                        
                        if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                            $email =$_POST['email'];
                            $bytes = random_bytes(5);
                            $token =bin2hex($bytes);
    
                            include "mail_reset.php";
                            if($enviado){
                            $link->query(" insert into passwords(email, token, codigo)
                            values('$email','$token','$codigo') ") or die($link->error);
                            echo '<p>Verifica tu email para restablecer tu contraseña</p>';
    
    }
                        }else{
                             echo "El email No existe";
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo "UUPS! Algo salió mal, inténtalo mas tarde";
                    }
                }
            }
    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como te mencionaron no capturas el dato **email** enviado por el formulario, ademas es buena practica validar que lleguen los datos, intenta con esto.

```js
<?php
include "conexion.php";
$email = "";
$email_alert = "";
$bytes = random_bytes(5);
$token =bin2hex($bytes);
$codigo = 0;

//COMPRIBAMOS QUE EL DATO FUE RECIBIDO
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
  //GUARDAMOS EL DATO EN EUNA VARIABLE
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  //EJECUTAMOS LA CONSULTA PARA VERIFICAR SI EXISTE, TAMBIEN PUEDE SER CON LIKE
  $query = $link->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE email= '$email'");
  $stmt->execute(array($email));
  $emailExiste = $stmt->fetchColumn();

  //SI EXISTE EJECUTAMOS LA CONSULTA
  if ($emailExiste > 0) {
    //CON INCLUDE_ONCE EVITAMOS CONFLICTOS POR DUPLICIDAD DE INCLUCIONES
    include_once "mail_reset.php";
    
    //AQUI NO SE DE DONDE OBTIENES "CODIGO", CREO QUE TE FLATO DECLARARLO
    $link->query(" insert into passwords(email, token, codigo)
    values('$email','$token','$codigo') ") or die($link->error);
    $email_alert = "Se ha enviado tu código para restablecer la contraseña";

  }else {
    //$email_alert = "No existe ninguna cuenta asociada al correo";
    //EJECUTA ALERT CON MENSAJE
    echo '<script>alert("No existe ninguna cuenta asociada al 
    correo")</script>';
  }
  
}else{
    echo '<script>alert("No recibí ningún dato")</script>';
}
?>
```

No se de donde obtienes el valor de **codigo**, la declare vacia para evitar errores, dime si funciona, si falta algo mencionalo y actualizo la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder, sin embargo el método que me compartiste no funciono. En un momento anexaré la manera en la que pude resolverlo.